# How to map the factors analysis result from array into DataFrame?

Tags: python

when doing the factor analysis with `factor_analyzer` lib, the result will show in array number without the observing variables' name. Please help me how to show it in DataFrame!

```
fa = FactorAnalyzer(7,rotation="varimax")
fa.fit(df)
fa.loadings_
```

Answer (score 0):

hope you've already figured this out but replying in case anyone else wants to know.

```
loadings = fa.loadings_
pd.DataFrame.from_records(loadings)
```